# SciPy: n-dimensional interpolation of sparse data

Tags: python, optimization, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I currently have a collection of n-dimensional data points, each with a [image: chi2] value associated with it (n typically will range from 2 to 4).

I would like to employ some form of non-linear interpolation on the data points I am supplied with so that I can try and minimise this [image: chi2] value. Of course, I am open to better methods of minimising the [image: chi2] value.

At the moment, I have code that works for 1D and 2D arrays

```
mesh = np.meshgrid(*[i['grid2'] for i in self.cambParams], indexing='ij')
chi2 = griddata(data[:,:-1], data[:,-1], tuple(mesh), method='cubic')
```

However scipy.interpolate.griddata only supports linear interpolation above 2D grids, meaning interpolation is useless as the minimum will be a defined point in the data. Does anyone know of an alternate interpolation method that might work, or a better way of solving the problem in general?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Received a tip from an external source that work, so posting the answer in case it helps anyone in the future.

SciPy has an Rbf interpolation method (radial basis function) which allows better than linear interpolation at arbitrary dimensions.

Taking a variable `data` with rows of `(x1,x2,x3...,xn,v)` values, the follow code modification to the original post allows for interpolation:

```
rbfi = Rbf(*data.T)
mesh = np.meshgrid(*[i['grid2'] for i in self.cambParams], indexing='ij')
chi2 = rbfi(*mesh)
```

The documentation [here is useful](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.Rbf.html#scipy.interpolate.Rbf), and there is a simple and easy to follow example [here](http://geoexamples.blogspot.com.au/2012/03/creating-grid-from-scattered-data-using.html), which will make more sense than the code snippet above.